# Hover over image - effect on another image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, onmouseover

I'm trying to make a portfolio where hover over a thumbnail causes the full picture to slide in from the left edge. All the css3 codes for animation work on the object the code is applied to, but what I want is, you hover over one object and the animation happens on the other object... I'm a noob and I just want my own portfolio for my pictures, so if anyone would help me a little I would be really happy! Thank you.

Comment: Are you try some thing ? If YES , then show the code experts definitly helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this jsfiddle looks like answer to your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/a3y52/

Essentially , you may want to use hover on
your object with id #one and the after effect on your other object with id

## three.

`#one:hover ~ #three`

I hope it helps.

Thanks,
Charles.